# sql debugging in vs2010 confusion

Tags: sql-server-2008, debugging, sqlclr

After much work i've configured my machine (win 7 x64, VS2010, SQL 2008 R2) to be able to debug stored procedures locally from within visual studio. My question is about how the debugging context is supposed to switch as you debug.

an example:

when debugging and I call another vb class the debugger follows and jumps to that class for me to step through. when I hit a sql call is there a way to tell the debugger to follow it there too?

currently the only way I can debug a stored procedure is to right click it and choose "step into" and provide values. Those values I have to determine by running my app, making edits, and writing down my param values I was going to pass into the stored procedure. Then going back and stepping into the stored procedure with those values allows me to track and use intellesense to debug the sql stuff.

What i'm looking for though is to have the debugger do the switching for me. So I don't have to do as much work to step through stored procedures. When I run my application and open one of my stored procedures to view the breakpoint symbols are not loaded but it does say it has auto-attached to the sql process and everything.

Wasn't sure if this was how sql debugging was supposed to go or if I did something incorrectly. Figured someone here might know what was going on. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my target framework was dot net 4 client profile. When I swapped to full dot net 4 framework and rebuilt everything started working like I thought it should. My only guess is that some of the sql-clr debugging stuff is trimmed out of the client profile?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

The standard workflow to debug a CLR SQL assembly is the following…

1. Right-Click the project and select ‘Deploy’
2. Debug | Attach to Process…
3. Select the Process ‘sqlservr.exe’ and make sure it is the one with a Type of ‘T-SQL, Managed, x86  or x64’
4. Press the Attach Button